# How to install Maven 2 plugin for Eclipse on 64-bit linux?

Tags: linux, eclipse, maven-2, 64-bit, fedora11

I have Fedora 11 (x86 64) installed with Eclipse.  I need a Maven plugin, preferrably m2eclipse, but I cannot find out how to install it.  I've tried going through yum, but to no avail (I can't even find any maven plugins).

On my other laptop, I've tried installing the plugin using yum on a 32 bit install of Fedora 11, and while the package shows as being installed, I still don't see it in Eclipse.  I've even tried starting eclipse with the clean flag.

Could anyone provide me with help?  I've got maven 2.0.4 installed.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to install the core components of the m2eclipse plugin after I first installed the ganymede packages from their update site:
http://download.eclipse.org/releases/ganymede/

Apparently "Fedora Eclipse" is not a flavor of the ganymede build.

Comment: Actually, the latest build (at least for most platforms) is Galileo (3.5 vs. 3.4).

Comment: Interesting.  Fedora 11 comes with 3.4.2 and I ran a yum update but it says there are no updates.  I might just uninstall Fedora Eclipse and get the regular version.

Comment: Galileo just came out at the end of June.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following update site: http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/update/

It's typically under `Help` -> `Software Updates…` and then you can add a new update site. Use the one above and you should have the option to install the plugin.

Comment: I tried this, but I haven't been able to track down all the dependencies and I'm starting to wonder if they're all available for 64 bit Eclipse on linux.  Is there an easy way to locate the update sites for all the dependencies needed?  I've been googling packages like "org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi update site" for each missing dependency and I don't feel like I'm getting anywhere.  I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

Goto Eclipse->Help->Install New Software...

Add the following update site in Eclipse
http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/sites/m2e
and enable the repository for your release of eclipse under "Available Software Sites" as well (which is disabled in Fedora by default).

Afterwards the installation in Eclipse should work without any missing dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I was hitting the same problem; evlipse installs it but the plugin isn't visible in the list nor are any of the features it should offer (such as a maven import wizard).

java 6, ubuntu, eclipse downloaded from the official site.

I removed ~/.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_3.5.0_1020258342
Started eclipse again
added the EMF update site
added the IAM site
installed eclipse IAM core, said no to resarting the workspace, quit eclipse
started eclipse

and its working.